# Manipulation of sympy Functions

Tags: python, sympy

I am working over arbitrary discrete functions like x<sub>1</sub>(k), x<sub>2</sub>(k), etc. where k is an Integer, and for any k, x<sub>i</sub>(k) is a real number (however, I might add that for the symbolic computations I want to perform, this is not relevant).

I need to manipulate those functions symbolically, i.e., I need to be able to perform typical operations like multiplication or addition of these functions (e.g. x<sub>1</sub>(k)*x<sub>2</sub>(k)) as well as manipulation of their arguments (e.g. x<sub>1</sub>(2*k+1)). Due to the argument manipulation, I can not just use sympy's Symbol class because they do not have arguments. Instead, sympy's Function class supports arguments and I thought that is exactly what I need. But for things like `x1*x2` it throws

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for *: 'UndefinedFunction' and 'UndefinedFunction'
```

Thus, I am not quite sure if the Function class is even suited for what I am looking for, or if I am just misunderstanding how to achieve what I need. How can I use sympy for these kind of computations?

**EDIT:**
For clarification, (before I knew that the `cls` option existed in sympy.Symbol) I thought that

```
import sympy as sp

x1 = sp.Symbol("x1")
```

wasn't going to work, due to the lack of arguments. So I tried

```
k = sp.Symbol("k")
x1 = sp.Function("x1")(k)
```

which would have arguments, but throw the error for things like `x1*x1`. Hope that is more clear.

**Follow up question:** As suggested in the answer of ForceBru, if I use

```
k = sp.Symbol("k")
x1 = sp.symbols("x1", cls=sp.Function)(k)
x2 = sp.symbols("x2", cls=sp.Function)(k)
```

then this seems to do the trick. However, what I also need to do is raise the argument by an integer j, i.e., I might have an expression like 2x<sub>1</sub>(2*k+1)x<sub>2</sub>(2*k+3) (or even more complicated) which after applying this operation returns 2x<sub>1</sub>(2*k+1+j)x<sub>2</sub>(2*k+3+j). Can't really use `expr.args` since that would not only return the arguments of x<sub>1</sub> and x<sub>2</sub>. Also, `expr.subs` may likely be risky to use if not only arguments of x<sub>1</sub> and x<sub>2</sub> are affected.

Do you see any way how this can be achieved?

**EDIT2:** After playing around more I have come to what seems to work by using `expr.atoms(sp.Function)` which returns a list of functions which can then be replaced by (j-times) shifted versions of themselves. Will accept FroceBru's answer as this was the crucial hint.

Comment: I'm hesitant to downvote this because I think this is the basis for a good question but it really isn't clear at this point. Could you perhaps expand this with what you specifically trying to do right now and the steps you've taken? I'm asking because I can't tell if you've constructed a symbolic expression or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code tries to multiply the function themselves, not the result of their *application*.

> I need to be able to perform typical operations like multiplication or addition of these functions (e.g. `x1(k)x2(k)`)

You can do this like this:

```
>>> import sympy as sp
>>> x1, x2 = sp.symbols("x_1 x_2", cls=sp.Function)
>>> k = sp.Symbol('k')
>>> x1(k) * x2(k) # simple multiplication
x_1(k)*x_2(k)
>>> x1(2*k + 1) * x2(3*k + 2) # argument manipulation
x_1(2*k + 1)*x_2(3*k + 2)
```

The difference is that `x1 * x2` attempts to multiply the functions themselves, but it doesn't make much sense, unless `*` means convolution. For example, what's `sin * cos`? On the contrary, `x1(k) * x2(k)` is a reasonable expression, just like `sin(x) * cos(x)`, because it's a product of the *results* of applying `x1` and `x2` to `k`.

Comment: Well, I meant the expression to be elementwise indeed. Interesting, I didn't come across the cls option yet. Will play around with that. Thanks a lot!